# sqlite can not create table

Tags: android, sqlite

I write SQL code at small android application, always database create successfully, but that is not correct for the table.

```
public dbSqlHelper dbHelper;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    dbHelper = new dbSqlHelper(this);

    SQLiteDatabase dataSql = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}
```

that is the main, and the following code for dbhelper

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "malekData.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private Context context;

public dbSqlHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

}

@Override
public void onCreate( SQLiteDatabase db) {
    try {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE malekDB4 ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT);");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.e("Malek", "Error when creating table: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
```

when I go to terminal and check table (.tables), no thing return

Comment: First uninstall the app from the device and rerun to recreate the database.

Comment: I try that, and test with device and simulator, try with (invalidate caches / restart ), and no result

Comment: Is the database created inside the device or not?

Comment: database create successfully, problem with the table

Comment: Then try with a clean device.

Comment: when I go to terminal to check table, no thing found, I copy create table statement from the code and paste in the terminal, for first time execute it is return error, but when re-execute, table was created :( that is like magic

Comment: You must extract the database from the device and inspect it. In Android Studio open *Device File Explorer* and then go to `data/data/<your-package-name>/databases/` copy the database and check.

Comment: I run now with semiulator, is that have problem?

Comment: No, the database should be created in the emulator.